# Search tool with file content indices

Tags: linux, locate

Are there any file search tools like gnome-search-tool (gui where I can select several options, like age of file, file-size, owner, etc) that uses DB indices for not only the file name but the file content as well.

I know `locate` has index, but I don't think it does file content.

Answer (score 0):

A completely free search tool with in-file search is [Lookeen Free](https://free.lookeen.com/).

Addition: I work for the vendor of Lookeen Free.

Comment: Seems like a windows only solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can always combine `find` and `grep`, `find` to filter on meta-data and `grep` to search content.

An example:

`find ./ -mtime -1 -type f -exec grep "test" {} +`

This would select any file (`-type f` filters only files)

in the current directory (`./` indicated the current directory)

modified in the last day (`-mtime -1` means modified is between now and -1 day)

and search them for the text "test" (`-exec grep "test" {} +` causes grep to be called once on all the files that `find` matches)

You can use `man find` and `man grep` as references. I recommend `find`/`grep` combo because it has so many options. `find` can search for things like:

- creation time
- last access time
- last modify time
- whether it's executable
- group that owns it
- name matches a regex
- permissions of the file
- size
- user that owns it

and many more, especially when combined with `-exec` and `stat`

I know it doesn't use an index this way, but it is a powerful option for searching for file content in specific files.

Comment: The gnome-search-tool I mentioned does all of this already.